# Javascript. Delayed div creation with

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to delay creation of each div by 1 sec to no avail, Can't figure out how to use setTimeout or setInterval, any help appreciated.
(also, would like to position divs centered relative to each other).
I'm trying to draw series of them of decreasing sizes, in each other.
Any advice appreciated

```
var i;
var w = 400;
var delay = 3000;
$(function () {
    $("#boom").click(function () {
        for (w, i = 0; w >= 20; i++, w = w - 20) {
            $('body').append('<div id="div' + i + '" />'); {
                if (i % 2 === 0) {
                    $("#div" + i + "").css({
                        "background-color": "gold",
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "z-index": i,
                        "top": "20vw",
                        "left": "20vw",
                    }).width(w).height(w);
                } else {
                    $("#div" + i + "").css({
                        "background-color": "chartreuse",
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "z-index": i,
                        "top": "20vw",
                        "left": "20vw",
                    }).width(w).height(w);
                }
            }
        }

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Kwadrat w kwadracie</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <button id="boom">Vamos!</button>
    <div id="outer"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can wrap the contents of `for` with a self-invoking function. Simmilar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46191194/6586663) answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I exactly understood what is your desired result, but I think this is what you are trying to achieve:

```js
const outerDiv      = document.getElementById('outer'),
      sizeDecrement = 20;

document.getElementById('boom').addEventListener('click', event => {
  let lastDiv = outerDiv,
      size    = 400;

  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = 'inner ' + (size % (2 * sizeDecrement) === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd');
    [div.style.height, div.style.width] = [size + 'px', size + 'px'];

    lastDiv.append(div);
    lastDiv = div;
    
    size -= sizeDecrement;
    if (size < sizeDecrement) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.inner {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.inner.odd {
  background-color: chartreuse;
}
.inner.even {
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Kwadrat w kwadracie</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <button id="boom">Vamos!</button>
  <div id="outer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, regarding your code: `$(function () {` is unnecessary, and so is using such an amount of per-div styling instead of creating a class and giving it those styles in style sheet.

Comment: I need them to be nested and keep decreasing in size :) for now i did it with delay and fadein ( ...  }).width(w).height(w).delay(i * 1000).fadeIn(200);  ), but it's kind of hacky, I needed delayed creation

Answer (score 0):

See following snippet. I hope it will help

```js
var i = 0;                     
var w = 400;
var delay = 500;


$(function () {
    $("#boom").click(myLoop);
});

function myLoop () {    


   setTimeout(function () {    
      
      $( i === 0 ? 'body' : '#div'+(i-1)).append('<div id="div' + i + '" />');            
                
                    $("#div" + i + "").css({
                        "background-color": i % 2 === 0 ? "gold" : "chartreuse",
                        "position": "relative",
                        "z-index": i,
                        "top": i === 0 ? "20vw": "10px",
                        "left": i === 0 ? "20vw": "10px",
                    }).width(w).height(w);
      
      i++;
      w = w - 20
      
      if (w >= 20) {            
         myLoop();             
      }      
   }, delay)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="boom">Vamos!</button>
    <div id="outer"></div>
```

See [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/malik_nasir/mgpmr5h7/2/) also